# How do i set up an offline website for testing on mobile AND desktop?

Tags: testing, mobile, blackberry, localhost

I've started work on a new website and from day 1 i want to ensure my site looks neat and tidy both on mobile and desktop, so i've decided to start developing both in sync with eachother, but the only issue is i don't have a clue how to set it up offline. Online would be pretty easy as i would have a web page to visit but because the offline set is set up to be a localhost page on my PC i can't access it on my mobile. Anybody know how to solve this issue?

Comment: If it is possible to access the localhost from a device simulator then testing the site in simulator may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make some change on your webserver :
 Modify the file :
webgrind.conf
 as follows :

```
Alias /webgrind "c:/wamp/apps/webgrind1.0/" 

# to give access to webgrind from outside 
# replace the lines
#
#        Order Deny,Allow
#   Deny from all
#   Allow from 127.0.0.1
#
# by
#
#        Order Allow,Deny 
#   Allow from all
#

<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/webgrind1.0/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

in case of wampserver it can be found in [yourwampdirectory/alias]

Comment: What do you mean by wamp? I don't have any folders in my C drive called wamp?

Comment: what webserver are you using to host the page locally? the thing here is that your webserver is usually not configured to allow connections from outside the local machine. once you make changes to allow incoming connections you can simply access your machine by: http://yourmachineslocalip/

Comment: If I have correctly understood what you are asking then it is IIS

Comment: there should be an option to allow incoming connections somewhere on your iis control panel. enable that and you should be good to go!

Comment: I've had a look through but i can't really find a great deal. Also would allowing these incoming connections only allow systems on this network to access it? (i'd assume that would be the case)

Comment: might be that your antivirus software or firewall is blocking your incoming connections and there is no configuration needed at all...about computers outside the network accessing your page that wouldnt be an issue because you might be inside a NAT configured by your router...outside connections would require you to further configure your router for forwaring port 80 traffic to your local machine.

Comment: I've set it to allow any incoming connections and i've connected to the network on my mobile phone, however when typing in the IPv4 address it just returns a 404. So frustrating it's something that i bet is SO simple but i have not got a clue how to do it :(

Comment: if you are not developing an ASP site try installing wampserver and configuring it as mentioed above. that'd do it!

Comment: Are there no other alternatives? I'd prefer not to install wampserver.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30751/discussion-between-niraj-adhikari-and-leeb)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using an user agent switcher-plugin for your browser.
There you can switch between devices with a simple click.

For Chrome:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg

For Firefox:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/developers

Comment: Once again, this provides an answer on how to change content between desktop and handheld, but it does not provide an answer to the question of "how do i set up my offline website to display on mobile"